# Here is a new type of ad javascript by change "window.opener.location", how can i block it?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, ads

One of my friend climes that his Chrome browser tab sometimes changed into "tamll.com", which was the biggest shopping website in China.

At first I think it may be caused by a malware. But he has a clean os, and he checked everything in his computer.

Then I found [this javascript](http://nv-gboy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/navigatoral.js). The code is always in the bottom of this question. And this script is being included in "bbs.gfan.com".

The script use window.opener.location to change another browser tab's webpage. When you open any pages in "bbs.gfan.com" from google.com(for example search "bbs.gfan.com" in google and click the first answer), this script check if the window.opener is not null, and set the window.opener.location to _5had0w.mall. Then the window.opener tab will be jumped to the new address.

Is there any way to block a script when it try to change window.opener.location? Or is there a way to directly disable the window.opener.location?

I think a normal webpage will never change this variable, it may only use by a ad script like this.

This kind of ad script made me feel sick. It is not only open a ad webpage but also another webpage will gone...

```
if ("undefined" == typeof (_5had0w)) {
  _5had0w = [];
  _5had0w.ssite = new RegExp("(www.baidu.com)|(www.google.c)|(www.youdao.com)|(search.cn.yahoo.com)|(search.yahoo.com)|(114search.118114.cn)|(bing.118114.cn)|(search.114.vnet.cn)|(bing.com)|(www.soso.com)|(www.sogou.com)|(www.taobao.com)|(gougou.com)|(www.gouwo.com)|(cache.baidu.com)|(m.baidu.com)|(baidu.asp)|(hao123.com)|(265.com)|(114la.com)|(115.com)|(etao.com)", "i");
  _5had0w.win = window;
  try {
    if (parent && parent.f && parent.document.getElementById("fulliframe")) {
      _5had0w.win = parent
    }
  } catch (e) {}
  _5had0w.getcookie = function (sName) {
    var aCookie = document.cookie.split("; ");
    for (var i = 0; i < aCookie.length; i++) {
      var aCrumb = aCookie[i].split("=");
      if (sName == aCrumb[0]) return unescape(aCrumb[1])
    }
    return ""
  };
  _5had0w.setcookie = function (sValue) {
    date = new Date();
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 100);
    document.cookie = "oc_busy=" + escape(sValue) + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + ";path=/"
  };
  _5had0w.mall = "http://gomallg.blogbus.com/?76";
  _5had0w.np = false;
  _5had0w.nvIt = function (lochref) {
    try {
      _5had0w.win.opener.location = lochref
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        _5had0w.win.opener.navigate(lochref)
      } catch (e2) {
        try {
          _5had0w.win.opener.opener.navigate(lochref)
        } catch (e3) {
          _5had0w.np = true
        }
      }
    }
  };
  _5had0w.nvUrl = function () {
    var _co = _5had0w.getcookie("oc_busy");
    if (_co == "" || _co.indexOf("mall") < 0) {
      _5had0w.nvIt(_5had0w.mall);
      if (!_5had0w.np) {
        _5had0w.setcookie(_co + "_mall")
      }
    }
  };
  _5had0w.oload = function () {
    if (_5had0w.win.opener && "" == _5had0w.getcookie('rf6_auth')) {
      if (_5had0w.ssite.test(_5had0w.win.document.referrer)) {
        _5had0w.nvUrl()
      }
    }
  };
  try {
    if (document.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent("onload", _5had0w.oload)
    } else {
      window.addEventListener("load", _5had0w.oload, false)
    }
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to happen for me, can you specify which browsers are affected by this?

Answer (score 0):

This web application is taking advantage of the fact that Google and other websites are being opened from gfan.com. Therefore, the gfan.com web application does have some control over the new windows, since it opened them.

If the script at the bottom of the application is what you suspect is causing the problem, you could try one of several adblockers you can get for Chrome and Firefox that are installable as extensions.

If that doesn't work, you could try to edit your host file and point the remote script's domain to 127.0.0.1 so you override the DNS locally. This assumes it is a remote script and not served from gfan.com itself; otherwise, you won't be able to access gfan.com either.

[Chrome Adblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) is an adblocker you can try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed Adblock and AdblockPlus was not work for this script. I wanna find a way to directly disable the window.opener.location, since I think it would never be used by a normal website.

Comment: Do this, run `window.open("http://google.com");` in your Chrome console. In the popup window, run `window.opener`. It will tell you that you can't access stackoverflow.com because of cross-domain security. If a script is using window.opener, it's a popup window that was opened by another page on that same domain. In order to get around this, you'd need a Chrome extension that redefines or nullifies the window.opener object itself.

Comment: The error caused by cross-domain security is for the chrome console, not for the script itself. The chrome console can shows what is in the object, and when the script in the console try to access the object window.opener, it was denied. So if you type "window.opener", the output in the console shows there is nothing in the object, but actually was. The script in the webpage can use "window.opener.location".

Comment: The "window.opener.location" seems to be a function. I try to delete the function, but failed. It will work if I use "delete(window.opener);" or "window.opener=null;". But it doesn't worked when I try to use "delete(window.opener.location);" or "window.opener.location=null". In the first case, the function returns false, and in the second case the opener tab jumped into the website in the current tab. Is it the only way I can do is "1.copy everything not location in the window.opener into a new object. 2.delete window.opener. 3.set window.opener = the new object"?